# Usage of “hitch"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, semantics

I always see the expression “his breath hitched” or “his breathing hitched.” However, as far as I can tell in the dictionary, the word “hitched” does not denote anything I can relate to breathing. Of course I understand what people are trying to get at when they say that expression, but is it technically correct? Does it make sense, semantically?

Comment: How about "a temporary difficulty that causes a short delay" from http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hitch?

Comment: I've certainly heard/read it used many times in a context which implies a metaphorical "hiccup".

Comment: It's always made sense to me. Collins has one definition as "a short, sudden movement or pull", which is easier to associate with breathing than a "sudden jerking motion" other definitions describe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

> to hitch: to move **interruptedly** or with **halts and jerks** usually due to an obstruction or impediment

(Webster's Unabridged)

As others have noted in the comments, this meaning works with breathing very well.

Comment: Very well. I say an article criticizing the use of that phrase and that got me thinking (more like confused). Thank you.

Comment: No worries, glad our collective input helped.